# check if ArrayList contains elements using hql

Tags: java, hql

I'm using hql request to check if a column called SharedItems and mapped as java.util.ArrayList contains some text, like this:

```
where 'someText' in elements(SharedItems)
```

That's not working as expected When the 'SharedItems' column contains null values, it displays :

```
Wrapped Exception: null
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.search(XWikiHibernateStore.java:2398)
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.search(XWikiHibernateStore.java:2327)
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.search(XWikiHibernateStore.java:2315)
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiCacheStore.search(XWikiCacheStore.java:659)
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.search(XWiki.java:1747)
at com.xpn.xwiki.api.XWiki.search(XWiki.java:512)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor610.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.doInvoke(UberspectImpl.java:389)
at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:378)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:270)
... 137 more
```

Comment: is SharedItems initialized? it looks like it might not be

Comment: thx @John Kane , I tried to initialise all cells to empty arraylist but it seems that the exception persist.

Comment: the cells? is the arraylist null?

Comment: sorry maybe my comment a little confusing due to my poor english :(, I initialized all the cells in the column 'SharedItems' of my table using new ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

I found the response to this issue [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html):

> Note that these constructs - size, elements, indices, minindex,
>   maxindex, minelement, maxelement - can only be used in the where
>   clause in Hibernate3.
>
> Elements of indexed collections (arrays, lists, and maps) can be
>   referred to by index in a where clause only.